# Modify modal dialog box in google forms based on user action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

### **What I'm Trying To Do**

I'm trying to add HTML to a modal dialog box in google Forms using a click event to trigger a `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` call to supply the new HTML in order to get additional user input.

GS Code

```
function onOpen(e) {
  FormApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu").addItem('Set Up Invites', 'setUpInvite').addToUi();
}

function setUpInvite() {
  //this is the main function
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle("Setup");

  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, "Setup");
}

function getEventQAnswer(answer) {
  var html;
  switch(answer)
  {
    case "yes":
      //TODO
      //get the event info
      return "";
      break;

    case "no":
      //create the event
      html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("createEvent.html")
      return html;
      break;
  }
}
```

### **HTML Index Page**

On this page I'm trying to change the get the functions to work onclick. I tried initially onchange, but it still didn't work. It starts with getSelectAnswer which gets the value from the select question, then calls the GS function getEventQAnswer which gets the proper HTML from the server side and delivers it to function addHTMLChoice. However, at present, it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  //document.getElementById("eventQ").addEventListener("onchange", getSelectAnswer);
  document.getElementById("eventQ").onclick.getSelectAnswer();
  function addHTMLChoice(html) {
  var div = document.getElementById('eventInfo');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  }

  function getSelectAnswer() {
  var e = document.getElementById('eventQ');
  var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addHTMLChoice).getEventQAnswer(val);
  }

  </script>
  <form>
  <div>
  <select id="eventQ">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No, create one now</option>
  </select>

  </div>
  <div id="eventInfo">

  </div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the createEvent.html I'm trying to return in test.

```
<div>
    <input id="datetime" name="datetime" type="datetime-local">
    <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server-side code can only return certain type of parameters, described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values). Since you are trying to return an html object it is not passed to the client side (your Modal dialog). Hence, modify your server-side like so:

```
function getEventQAnswer(answer) {
  var html;
  switch(answer)
  {
    case "yes":
      //TODO
      //get the event info
      return "";
      break;

    case "no":
      //create the event
      html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("createEvent.html").asTemplate().getRawContent()
      return html;
      break;
  }
}
```

Note the conversion into RawContent.

Also, I find it easier to setup onchange event trigger to obtain the choice, like so:

```
<form>
  <div>
  <select id="eventQ" onchange ='getSelectAnswer()'>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No, create one now</option>
  </select>

  </div>
```

The final html index code will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  //document.getElementById("eventQ").addEventListener("onchange", getSelectAnswer);
  //document.getElementById("eventQ").onclick.getSelectAnswer();
  function addHTMLChoice(html) {
  console.log("success")
  console.log(html)
  var div = document.getElementById('eventInfo');
  div.innerHTML = html;
  }

  function getSelectAnswer() {
  console.log("getting selected Answer")
  var e = document.getElementById('eventQ');
  var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(val)
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addHTMLChoice).withFailureHandler(failed).getEventQAnswer(val);
  }
  
  function failed(e){
  console.log("Failed")
  console.log(e)
  }

  </script>
  <form>
  <div>
  <select id="eventQ" onchange ='getSelectAnswer()'>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No, create one now</option>
  </select>

  </div>
  <div id="eventInfo">

  </div>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note, the use of `console.log` to debug on the client side. This would be useful in future for your own debugging.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a million. I've read the HTMLService documentation what feels like a million times and totally missed or misunderstood the whole legal return types thing. And I had no idea I could use console.log() with the GAS development environment, but figured it out by inspecting element on my firefox browser. Game changer - I've been doing it blind off and on for over a year and a half.